# Haskell : Function get several types of variables

Tags: haskell

I have to make a function which will be able to get two types of variables as input either String or [Int].

Here is my work. It takes as argument a list of lists and check if all the lists have the same length. If yes it shows (m,n) where m is the number of lists the List has and n the length of all the lists (which is the same).

```
size :: [[Int]] -> (Int,Int)
size a = size2 a m n
  where
  m = 0
  n = length (head a)

size2 :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)
size2 [] m n = (m,n)
size2 a m n
    |  n == length (head a) = size2 (tail a) (m+1) n
    |  otherwise = (0,0)
```

I made it work with [[Int]], and it must be don't to work also on [String] Input.

Comment: Just remove the type annotations, and it will do (most likely).

Comment: @Ingo Sorry but I don't understand. Write me please the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature of `size` should be `size :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int)`. Here `a` is type variable, and can be any type.

It's generalization of both `[[Int]] -> (Int, Int)` and `[String] -> (Int, Int)`, as `String` is the same as a list of characters `[Char]`.

Of course you have to change type of `size2` accordingly.

As a side note, it's better to change definition to return `Maybe (Int, Int)` type, so you can differentiate between different cases, `[]` and e.g. `[[1],[2,3]]`.

Comment: Lol, found the answer stupid, putting size :: [[a]]. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer would be to change the type signatures to

`size :: [[a]] -> (Int,Int)` and `size2 :: [[a]] -> Int -> Int -> (Int,Int)`

but there's also better ways to make this function, instead of going through the list yourself with `size2`, you can use functions that come in the `Prelude`

a good example of how to do it would be:

```
size :: [[a]] -> (Int, Int)
size [] = (0,0)
size ls@(x:xs) = 
    if all (\s -> length x == length s) xs 
        then (length ls, length x) 
        else (0,0)
```

Which is saying: if all the lists have the same size as the first list, then return the `tuple`, else, return the `(0,0)`

This works, but how to make a difference between an empty list and a list that does not have all lists with the same size? we use `Maybe`

```
size :: [[a]] -> Maybe (Int, Int)
size [] = Just (0,0)
size ls@(x:xs) = 
    if all (\s -> length x == length s) xs 
        then Just (length ls, length x) 
        else Nothing
```

---

```
*Main> size []
Just (0,0)
*Main> size ["gola","asda"]
Just (2,4)
*Main> size ["gola","asda","s"]
Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make a custom data type that does what you want?

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
type CharsOrInts = Either [Char] [Int]
```

Now you can pattern match:

```
size Left x = foo x
size Right x = bar x
```

such that foo :: String -> YourOutputType, bar :: [Int] -> YourOutputType